# SQL Update Column based on separate table conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've the task of updating several entries in a database.

Two tables need to be connected by an Id.  One is an account table and the other is a territory table.

I have a TerritoryID in the Account table, and that entry will have to be updated with the Id of a territory based off of it's DisplayName.

**ACCOUNT TABLE**

AccountId
TerritoryId << I need to populate this.

**TERRITORY TABLE**
Id
DisplayName

I have a spreadsheet with AccountId's and DisplayNames.  I need a query that will update one table based on one condition (accountId) with a value based on another condition from another table (based on DisplayName).

I've been trying things similar to:

```
UPDATE 
 [dbo].[Account] 
SET 
 TerritoryId = [dbo].[Territories].Id 
FROM Accounts ON WHERE AccountId = '6477026' SELECT Id FROM Territories WHERE DisplayName LIKE '%partialDisplayName'
```

I was also trying to integrate a `CASE` statement in there.  I just can't seem to make anything stick, though.
The potential duplicate answers I've found don't see to take **two** conditions from **two** separate tables into consideration.

Comment: What is your dbms?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help.  It's not clear how you are determining which `TerritoryId` to assign to which `AccountID`

Comment: SSMS 14 is the dbms

Comment: I think you mean SQL Server 2014? SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is the client tool for SQL Server.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky SSMS is just client tool that you use to interact with the database.  Your database will be SQL Server.  So add SQL Server tag to your question.  Better yet, add the version of the SQL Server as well.

Comment: Make sure you tag properly.  It's useless for you if people provide you solution to the wrong dbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a fabrication of your problem. Your tables...

```
create table #account (
  accountId int not null primary key
, territoryID int null
)

create table #territory (
  territoryId int not null primary key
, displayName varchar(20)
)
```

Some sample data...

```
insert into #territory values (1, 'Hell');
insert into #territory values (2, 'heaven');
insert into #territory values (3, 'purgatory');

insert into #account values (1, 0)
insert into #account values (2, 0)
insert into #account values (3, 0)
insert into #account values (4, 0)
insert into #account values (5, 0)
insert into #account values (6, 0)
insert into #account values (7, 0)
insert into #account values (8, 0)
```

> I have a spreadsheet with AccountId's and DisplayNames. I need a query
>   that will update one table based on one condition (accountId) with a
>   value based on another condition from another table (based on
>   DisplayName).

**Option-1:** In excel, craft the update statements, copy those statements from Excel to your query editor, and run them. The query looks like the following:

```
UPDATE #account
SET territoryID = (SELECT territoryId FROM #territory WHERE displayName = '<name>')
WHERE accountID = <id>
```

**Option-2:** You import the spreadsheet's contents into Excel (lots of ways to do this, Google is your friend).

```
--Create table to store the temp data
CREATE TABLE #excel_stuff (accountId int, displayName varchar(20));

--Created insert statements for the data from the spreadsheet. Running
--the inserts.
insert into #excel_stuff values (1, 'heaven')
insert into #excel_stuff values (2, 'heaven')
insert into #excel_stuff values (3, 'hell')
insert into #excel_stuff values (4, 'heaven')
insert into #excel_stuff values (5, 'heaven')
insert into #excel_stuff values (6, 'purgatory')
insert into #excel_stuff values (7, 'purgatory')
insert into #excel_stuff values (8, 'hell')
```

At this point your Excel data is in the database. Now, I'll update the territoryId values in the #account table:

```
UPDATE #account
SET territoryID = (
SELECT t.territoryID
FROM #excel_stuff ex INNER JOIN #territory t
ON ex.displayName = t.displayName
WHERE ex.accountId = #account.accountId
)

DROP TABLE #excel_stuff;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can't wait to try this.  The sql statement seems like what I've been trying to land on.

Comment: The query seems good to go.  I'm not going to know for sure, as the DB Admin didn't give me CREATE permissions on Friday, but I think this may work.

Comment: If you prefer option-2, you can create a global session table and load your data into that. That won’t require create table permissions. The global session table will persist until all users using it disconnect - https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/tables/global_temp.php.